# How to create a Spec-Flow test for a Prism 7 app?

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, prism, specflow

I'm in the process of creating a new windows desktop app with Prism 7, and I started out with the new `PrismApplication` base class that replaced the bootstrapper. Everything was fine until I created the (specflow-)tests.

I was used to re-using the original bootstrapper during initialization of the test-app, just modifying the registrations afterwards. That, transformed to the new `Application` derived system looks like this:

```
internal partial class App
{
    protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
    {
        var containerExtension = new Prism.Unity.Ioc.UnityContainerExtension();
        containerExtension.Instance.AddExtension( new LogExtension() );
        return containerExtension;
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes( IContainerRegistry containerRegistry )
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<IConfiguration, AppSettingsConfiguration>();
        containerRegistry.Register<IWindowsInterface, WindowsInterface>();
        // ... a lot of registrations removed here ...
    }
}
```

And a derived test-app that does everything but create the shell:

```
private class MyApp : App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Wrapped up in a `BeforeScenario` hook to initialize the test-app:

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void InitializeApp()
{
    var app = new MyApp();
    app.Initialize();
    var containerRegistry = (IContainerRegistry)app.Container;

    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<TestWindowsInterface>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IWindowsInterface,TestWindowsInterface>();
    // ... some registration overrides removed here ...

    _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<App>( app );
}
```

And a step to create the main window (`CreateShell` replacement):

```
[When( @"I start the software" )]
public void WhenIStartTheSoftware()
{
    _container.RegisterInstanceAs( _container.Resolve<App>().Container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>() );
}
```

So far, so good, this works. But only as long as you have just one scenario. As soon as the second scenario starts, we get an exception:

```
Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.
```

In the old days, this wasn't a problem, because the `Bootstrapper` was just a regular class, as opposed to the `PrismApplication` which is enforced to be a singleton by the framework.

Of course, I can move the whole registration stuff into a regular class, and use that to initialize the test-app, but this means essentially creating my own version of the bootstrapper *on top* of the `PrismApplication`. Using the classic `Bootstrapper` makes more sense to me, yet it will be dropped in a future release (as it's marked obsolete today).

Comment: You'll either need to attach the current test to an existing application process, or after each scenario close the application down. Then before each scenario start the application.

Comment: You're going to automate testing of ui?  That's unusual.

Comment: @GregBurghardt the application is running withing the nunit runner within resharper, that's my problem: I cannot restart the process at will.

Comment: @Andy I do integration testing of the whole app minus the views and the attached hardware, from the view models down to simulated hardware. Testing the view models isn't _that_ unusual, and we drastically reduce manual testing effort this way, because the testers only have to check the views and the interaction with the real hardware... all the rest they receive pretested and they just test it for regulatory purposes.

Comment: You might need to add an `[AfterScenario]` hook to destroy/cleanup the application instance, maybe? I'm not familiar with Prism.

Comment: Testing viewmodels discretely is entirely usual. They aren't views though.

Comment: @GregBurghardt is there a way to remove an `Application` instance from the `AppDomain`? It's not Prism who's complaining, rather the net runtime.

Comment: @Andy of course, they are not. I'm running the full app headless within nunit, without the wpf framework and with some fake services so that, for example, prism's `ViewModelLocator` works without wpf. Thus, the closest I get to the views is the view models, and my specflow-steps operate on those, simulating a user interacting with the views (which aren't there during the test, as they are created through databinding by wpf, which, itself, isn't there). And using the real app is the problem, as there can only be one per app domain, and nunit reuses that for all the tests in an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to create several instance of the `Application` class using a class that derives from `MarshalByRefObject`:

```
public class AppDomainWrapper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var app = new MyApp();
        app.Initialize();
        ...
        app.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AppDomain");
AppDomainWrapper app = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(AppDomainWrapper).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AppDomainWrapper).FullName) as AppDomainWrapper;
app.DoSomething();
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
```

Comment: Will not everything created by `MyApp` be created in the wrapped `AppDomain`? and will not everything used outside need to be marshalled, too? All the steps are defined in the "regular" `AppDomain` and will run there.

Comment: @Haukinger: Yes, you can only create one `Application` per app domain.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for a way around that limitation.

Comment: @Haukinger: I thought I just gave you (the) one, i.e. create a new `AppDomain` for each `Application`.

Comment: I have to access the objects created by the app from outside the new `AppDomain`.

Comment: Do you? Isolate each test run in a separate `AppDomain`. Or mock away any use of the `App` class in your tests. These are your options.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, this is completely impractical - I can't write my own test runner, nor can I mock away the subject under test.

Comment: @Haukinger: And - again - nor can you create two `Application` objects in the same `AppDomain`.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to work around that so I don't _have_ to create multiple `Application` instances.

Comment: @Haukinger: So your issue is that `InitializeApp()` that crates the `App` runs more than once?

Comment: My issue's that the bootstrapping of the app has been moved into an object that can only be created once, so that I cannot reuse the bootstrapping within my test.

Comment: @Haukinger: It's a fact that the bootstrapping has moved so if you want to upgrade to Prism 7, you obviously need to rewrite your tests.

Comment: Luckily not, as the bootstrapper's still there, but I need a way to not duplicate hundreds of registrations when the bootstrapper goes away. This is a nightmare to keep in sync between tests and real app.